# Chrome CSS filter grayscale distorts image/text

Tags: css, grayscale, css-filters

The situation is simple:

I have content on a page and I want to grayscale it when it's printed. The way I've found to do this is with CSS filters

```
.body {
    filter: Gray();
    filter: url('#grayscale');
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Everything shows fine on the site but distorts when I try to print.

[Check out the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dp5f20eu/6/) (hit Ctrl-P and look at page 2 for the example.)

Has anyone seen this before? I am using Google Chrome v60.0.3112.113

Comment: Have you tried printing? Does it come out looking blurry?

Comment: @JaneDoe Printing comes out looking exactly like the preview. And it doesn't blur, but instead it's more of like a distort like pixelation

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to fix your problem, I came up with a small solution for the text, but unable to fix for the image.

I found that this works well for the text:

```
body {
  color: red;
}
@media print {
body {
    color: #000 !important;
  }
}
```

I hope it helps a little bit anyway... I made the text red just to prove that it changes the color in print mode. The text looks crisp, but the image is still an issue. Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, I mainly need the image grayscaled. I know that I can change the text color on print I mainly added the text part in to show that the filter distorts all elements, not just images.

Comment: @Hank I'm not sure if you can use Javascript, but I found a solution that turns an image into grayscale and it looks really good for printing.. https://codepen.io/duketeam/pen/ALEByA